# Use jQuery maths to add integer to each array object incrementally

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have a set of elements that use data values from an array and this works quite well. I'd like to add `5` to each value in the `placeme` array incrementally, i.e. if the first sibling's values are `'10,20,30'` the second sibling should have `'15,25,35'` and the third should have `'20,30,40'` and so forth but I'm not sure how to go about this.

This is my code so far:

**HTML**

```
<section data-alpha="200,500,1500,1590" data-beta="foo,bar,baz,norf">placeholder</section>
<section>placeholder</section>
<section>placeholder</section>
<section>placeholder</section>
<section>placeholder</section>
```

**jQuery**

```
var him = $("section:nth-of-type(1)").attr('data-alpha');
var useme = new Array();
useme = him.split(",");
for (a in useme ) {
    useme[a] = parseInt(useme[a]);
}

var her = $("section:nth-of-type(1)").attr('data-beta')
var placeme = new Array();
placeme = her.split(",");

$('section').each(function(){
    $(this).attr('data-'+useme[0]+'',placeme[0]);
    $(this).attr('data-'+useme[1]+'',placeme[1]);
    $(this).attr('data-'+useme[2]+'',placeme[2]);
    $(this).attr('data-'+useme[3]+'',placeme[3]);
})
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mx5uo3fr/)

```js
var him = $("section:nth-of-type(1)").attr('data-alpha');
var useme = new Array();
useme = him.split(",");
for (a in useme ) {
    useme[a] = parseInt(useme[a]);
}

var her = $("section:nth-of-type(1)").attr('data-beta')
var placeme = new Array();
placeme = her.split(",");

$('section').each(function(){
    $(this).attr('data-'+useme[0]+'',placeme[0]);
    $(this).attr('data-'+useme[1]+'',placeme[1]);
    $(this).attr('data-'+useme[2]+'',placeme[2]);
    $(this).attr('data-'+useme[3]+'',placeme[3]);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<section data-alpha="200,500,1500,1590" data-beta="foo,bar,baz,norf">placeholder</section>
<section>placeholder</section>
<section>placeholder</section>
<section>placeholder</section>
<section>placeholder</section>
```

Comment: what is the desired output markup

Comment: Like that: http://jsfiddle.net/mx5uo3fr/1/ ???

Comment: @A.Wolff yes, that's it! Please post as an answer so I can accept. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to increment by 5 specifc `data-*` attributes regarding sibling index of each section, you can inside `each` loop using following logic:

```
$('section').each(function(i){ // 'i' is the index
    $(this).attr('data-'+(useme[0] + i*5),placeme[0]);
    $(this).attr('data-'+(useme[1] + i*5),placeme[1]);
    $(this).attr('data-'+(useme[2] + i*5),placeme[2]);
    $(this).attr('data-'+(useme[3] + i*5),placeme[3]);
});
```